# Facebook Graph API - attempting Facebook page create

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I attempt to create a new Facebook page (parent/child) using the Facebook Graph API (Graph API Reference /{page-id}/locations) I get the following error:

{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#371) You don't have permission to make the requested change.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 371
    }
}

any ideas?

Comment: Have you read the documentation that say: A page access token is required to publish existing locations to a page.
A page access token is required to create new locations and add them to a page. Only selected developers will have access to this functionality. Are you trying to the second thing? And if so have Facebook whitelisted you to do it?

Comment: Hey Wiz... we are whitelisted, so assuming that we do have access to this capability, and we are using a page access token..just trying to understand the error message, this was working earlier in the year, so not sure if it's a new version issue...

Comment: You can try to search for error codes here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#errors and http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Error_codes.

Comment: I'm trying to create a new Facebook page to be associated with a location in our app, a location that is not associated with any Facebook entity... this attempt is to create a new Facebook page with no Facebook parent... not sure it's possible... but I think you need a brand token not a page token, as there is no page, hence no page token

Comment: If you are whitelisted file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs